# $wpdb get_row populate session variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating a custom login page for users on a website based on wordpress.

When the user logs in I want to take there name from the database is place in into a session.

```
$login = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userAccount = %s AND userPass = %s AND enabled = 1", 
$account, $password));

if($wpdb->num_rows == 1){
       $_SESSION['username'] = $result->userName;
}
```

How can I get the results to populate the session because currently when calling

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

 }
```

The session is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $wpdb->get_var(query) instead.

Accordingly, use $wpdb->get_row() to retrieve a single row as a single object (or array), and $wpdb->get_results() to get a result set.

Above you haven't actually defined the $result var.